# Filtered Query in Elasticsearch Java API

Tags: elasticsearch

I am little bit confused while creating Filtered query in Elasticsearch Java API.
SearchRequestBuilder class has setPostFilter method, javadoc of this method clearly says that filter will be applied after Query is executed.

However, there is no setFilter method Or some other method which will allow to apply filter before
query is executed. How do I create filtered Query(which basically applies filter before query is executed) here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 FilteredQueryBuilder builder = 
 QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("test", 
 "test"),FilterBuilders.termFilter("test","test"));
```

It will build the filtered query...To filteredQuery, first argument is query and second arguments is Filter.

**Update:** Filtered query is depreciated in elasticsearch 2.0+.[refer](https://www.elastic.co/blog/better-query-execution-coming-elasticsearch-2-0)

Hope it helps..!

Comment: things have changed in API v. 2.0 and later. See my answer.

Answer (score 13):

`QueryBuilders.filteredQuery` is deprecated in API v. 2.0.0 and later.

Instead, filters and queries have "equal rights". `FilterBuilders` no longer exists and all filters are built using `QueryBuilders`.

To implement the query with filter only (in this case, geo filter), you would now do:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.geoDistanceQuery("location")
        .point(center.getLatitude(), center.getLongitude())
        .distance(radius, DistanceUnit.METERS);

// and then...
SearchResponse resp = client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery(query);
```

If you want to query by two terms, you would need to use `boolQuery` with `must`:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("user", "ben"))
            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("rank", "mega"));

// and then...
SearchResponse resp = client.prepareSearch(index).setQuery(query);
```

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html) there is a difference between a query and filter contexts, namely filtering is without scoring of matches and might perform better. Daphna, when using the API as suggested, can this achieved differentiation be achieved, or is scoring  implictly calculated (thus potentially taking away from performance)?

Comment: @YonatanWilkof That's a great question. You should ask it as a main question rather than in the comments thread, somebody might be able to help you.

Comment: It seems that by wrapping the query (a BoolQueryBuilder object) by giving it as an argument to boolQuery().filter(..) and then setting that in the setQuery() as you suggested- then this can be achieved. The "score" key in the response is always 0 (though documents are found)

Answer (score 8):

In case you just want to **execute filter without query**, you can do like this:

```
FilteredQueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(),
   FilterBuilders.termFilter("username","stackoverflow"));
```

Ref: [Filtering without a query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#_filtering_without_a_query)

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that by wrapping the query (a BoolQueryBuilder object) by giving it as an argument to boolQuery().filter(..) and then setting that in the setQuery() as you suggested- then this can be achieved. The "score" key in the response is always 0 (though documents are found)

Be careful here! If the score is 0, the score has been calculated. That means the query is still in query context and not in filter context. In filter context the score is set to 1.0 (without calculation) [source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)

To create a query in filter context without calculation of the score (score = 1.0) do the following (Maybe there is still a better way?):

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.constantScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "blub)));
```

This returns the same results like:

```
GET /indexName/typeName/_search 
    {
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              { "match": {
                "name": "blub"
              }}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Filter is used with bool. Please refer this doc
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Constant Query wraps a filter query and returns every matching document with a relevance score equal to the 'boost parameter value'
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html

Answer (score 1):

Since FilteredQueryBuilder is deprecated in the recent versions, one can use the `QueryBuilders.boolQuery()` instead, with a must clause for the query and a filter clause for the filter.

```
import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;

QueryBuilder builder = boolQuery().must(termQuery("test", "test")).filter(  boolQuery().must(termQuery("test", "test")));
```